# How to pass characters to a method/class as a string?

Tags: java, string, class, parameters

I'm attempting to write classes that will ultimately be part of a larger boggle program. One of my classes -- Tile -- stores the letter showing, the row and column where it is located on the board, and a flag to indicate if the tile has been selected by the player. 
I'm having trouble with the storing of the letter.

Initially, I stored the letter as a char -- as when new Tile objects are created, a char is passed to the constructor. However, I need to be able to store "Qu" as well. This leads me to believe the constructor for Tile needs to accept the letter as a string; however, when I create a new Tile object and pass it a character, it doesn't work.

For example:

```
Tile t1 = new Tile ('d', 0, 0);

Tile t2 = new Tile ("Qu", 0, 1);
```

Both of these need to work. But i'm unsure how to go about storing the letter (as a char? a string?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to support more than one character, you're right that you need a `String`. However, there's no requirement for a `String` to have more than one character. This is perfectly acceptable:

```
Tile t1 = new Tile("d", 0, 0);
```

I will note that the position of a tile isn't really an *inherent* property, and something like a `Tile[4][4]` might make more sense overall for keeping track of position.

**Update:** Based on additional information, it sounds like a poorly-written assignment requires both. In this specific case, use multiple constructors like this:

```
public Tile(char value, int x, int y) {
    this(Character.toString(value), x, y);
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. My only concern is I was given a Driver program in which some Tile objects were created using a character (such as new Tile('d', 0, 0)) while ones created with Qu were created with strings (new Tile("qu", 0, 1)). Maybe there is a fault with the driver program? Or should I be able to take both chars or strings?

For example, in the driver program, the Tile objects are an ArrayList and the following code is present
:
tiles.add(new Tile("qu",0,0));

tiles.add(new Tile('i',0,1));

tiles.add(new Tile('e',0,2));

tiles.add(new Tile('t',0,3));